# Dialog Connect to Server in Gnome Nautilus contains no items

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

I have installed Gnome Nautilus 2.28.4 on my Debian 5.0 box and a dialog File -> Connect to Server -> Service type is almost empty:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends
```